# USB devices not working after kernel downgrade

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb

The latest `apt-upgrade` caused my ubuntu 15.10 to freeze at the login screen (the cursor in the password line blinked once then freeze).

I tried to solve this problem by installing another kernel (both newer and older). Sadly I couldn't just use the previous kernel because that one was removed.
Using both the newer or older kernel solved my freeze problem but all USB devices stopped working in those versions.

Do you have any idea how to debug that? Is there some command that reconfigures the current kernel or something?

If someone has an idea how to fix the freeze I'd be glad to hear it.

Comment: What does "lsusb" show You ? And this question might be better placed in unix/linux SX site, and not here.

Comment: `lsusb` shows all devices correctly. They appear in `dmesg`, too. It seems everything is fine except that they are not responing. I can't mount USB drives(they don't appear as /dev/sdX), mouse/keyboard doesn't work and the internal sensors which seem to be connected via USB don't show up for the `sensors` program.

Comment: Dev is not being populated ? That is strange. Which modules are loaded ?

Comment: I found the problem. Somehow only a small subset of mods were loaded. I fixed it by installing `linux-image-generic` which was not installed somehow...